# How to initialize ionics "auto-lazy loading" stencil components properly?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, web-component, stenciljs

TLDR; I want to initialize all components at once using the `@ionic/core` npm package instead of `initialize()` and for each component `defineCustomElement()`

I started digging into ionic without frameworks (plain web components) and `npm i` the `@ionic/core` package. It's documentation says it has some "auto lazy-loading" stencil components to use out of the box by including the respective script tags (find the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/core)). This works without problems, like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="hydrated">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"
    ></script>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ion-button>Hello Button</ion-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also importing from `@ionic/core/components` and then initializing manually works well:

```js
import { initialize } from "@ionic/core/components";
import { defineCustomElement } from "@ionic/core/components/ion-button";

initialize();//initializes ionic and prepares the html
defineCustomElement();//initializes a certain type of element
```

The latter is said to be especially for projects using bundlers like webpack as only those components will be included in the package that were used.
While I understand why this is, I don't want it in my project. I want all components to be initialized like in the first example but I don't want to use the CDN, I want to use the npm package and just once call some function like `initialize`. As the CDN and the npm packages are said to be equal I thought I could just look after the path `@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js` but apperently this file does not exist in my `node_modules`. Now I'm a bit stuck. Anyone a suggestion how I can make this work?

I don't want to use the CDN because I use lot's of other libs in my project and manage everything via npm and it would anoy me to know I have this single dependency that needs special handling. Others than that I plan to build for iOS and Android natively with capacitor but have no experience and am unsure if the CDN usage would create problems in terms of offline functionality of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

Stencil acutally even uses ionic as the example. Find the solution [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript). To make it short. A Stencil built component library will have a folder "loader" in it's output. This contains a file index.es2017. You can `import { defineCustomElements } from "@ionic/core/loader/index.es2017";`.
`defineCustomElements()` will also `initialize()` the app with default config. I'm unsure if there is a better way to do things but explicitly calling `initialize()` before `defineCustomElements()` let's you then also pass a custom config (e.g. to switch modes from md to ios).

Comment: A real _lazy_ solution is to put the Web Component in a ``<script>`` tag at the _end_ of your HTML document; only drawback is ``DOMContentLoaded`` will fire later; but since you are now using Web Components, why use DCL anyway?

Comment: hmm... Why does it matter where in the DOM the `<script>` tag is for the lazy loading? To my understanding the idea of Stencils "auto lazy loading" components is to download the code to initialize a component only when it's initialized first time. Without looking into the docs I'd assume the `<script>` which you include will call the server whenever a new component is initialized and fetch it's code from the respective script. it does anyway not apply to my use case as I aimed to load all components at once. Mentioning the "auto lazy loading" feature of stencil was misleading from my end.

Comment: Yes, with ``A real lazy`` solution, I mean you the developer being lazy to achieve a lazy loading effect.

Comment: Related: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/

Comment: It should probably be noted that "I want to initialize all components at once" is generally a bad idea. Especially with the Ionic library which includes almost 100 components.

Comment: Yeah, well I guess it would be better to load only the ones in use actually but I write a host for micro-frontends and provide the components for the use by the micro-frontend devs. I cannot know which components they'll use. I could only write a wrapper that watches the dom on micro-frontend mounts and finds elements not yet initialized, then initialize them. However, I doubt this would performance wise do any better and I definitely know this is nothing for a PoC. I'm open for other ideas. So seriously, what would you propose as a better solution to initialize a shared component lib @G.Trant

Comment: As the saying goes, you can't eat your cake and then still have it. It sounds like you want the impossible: don't lazy load, don't load entire library, don't dynamically determine which components to load. Just magically load only the components being used. I have no solution for that other than the fact that Stencil gives you that out of the box which is dynamic lazy loading.

Comment: That's exactly not true. As I wrote, I would love to initialize components at runtime as soon as they were called the first time. Since the library does not provide this or I'm not aware of it, I want to statically load ALL components right from the beginning. This was what I didn't find in the first place and therefore asked. Ionic has something THEY call "auto-lazy loading" what you were punishing me for, but is not even a term coined by me. All I wanted was the answer I provided at the end and accepted. I was looking for the function that initializes all components.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Stencil docs to understand how they work and how they are distributed and initialized. I'm not specifically familiar with Ionic's components, but the`ionic.esm.js` reference suggests that it's a standard Stencil library which manages lazy loading through ionic.esm.js. That file will selectively and dynamically load any number of other files that are deployed along with ionic.esm.js, according to the page's DOM. There's nothing stopping you from bundling/deploying this library yourself along with the rest of your app - you would just need to change the source path of ionic.esm.js. But if you want to have your app load/initialize the components, you would probably need to clone the project and rebuild it using the dist-custom-elements output target and include them in your app deployment along with any initialization.